# Adding aligned image to table cell causes rendering bug in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, webpage-rendering

I have an image that is set to `vertical-align: text-top` inside a table cell. In Internet Explorer it renders correctly, but Chrome renders incorrectly:

**Internet Explorer 10** (10.0.9200.16660):

[image]

**Chrome 29** (29.0.1547.66 m):

[image]

*Updated to include* **Firefox 23** (23.0.1):

[image]

Three browsers, three behaviors; but only IE is what you expect.

You can [fiddle the glaving on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jURXz/).

---

The magic ingredient is the image in a table cell:

```
<td class="c1" rowspan="3">
   <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA....">
</td>
```

with the cell styled as `vertical-align: text-top`:

```
<style type="text/css">
   .c1 {vertical-align: text-top; }
</style>
```

The only workaround i've found is removing the `vertical-align: text-top`. But that causes it to render not how i want:

[image]

Since Chrome is the arbiter of all things good and correct, i must be doing something wrong. But what?

**Note**: The problem is not limited to inline data-uri images. i just use that so the problem is visible on jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `top` instead of `text-top`. Works for me. Also, you have forgotten to close your image tag!

Comment: `<image>` is a *"void"* element. As such it is forbidden from having a closing tag. [W3C: HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements) *"Void elements only have a start tag; end tags must not be specified for void elements."* Specifying `top` works; although the HTML spec should be updated to specify correct behavior of this case.

Comment: Still, using `<img />` instead of `<img>` seems more convenient (i was not talking about a closing tag, but to close your tag). Also, it no longer marks it red (=error) in jsfiddle.